# Proving the equivalence between an identity and a relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How could I prove that the identity $ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}
   = 1  $  is equivalent to the relation

$ (\frac{\partial x}{\partial y})^2 \frac{\partial^3 y}{\partial x^3}+3\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial y^2} + (\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})^2 \frac{\partial^3 x}{\partial y^3}
   = 0$ ?

I don´t know how to proceed since I don´t have very clear the difference between an identity and a relation. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I think you want to flip one of the derivatives in your identity. Try starting by differentiating the identity w.r.t $x$  twice and w.r.t $y$ twice

Answer (score 0):

The calculus below shows how to derive Eq.(2) from Eq.(1)

[image]